# When is further reduction than the order statistics not possible?

Tags: self-study, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from a population with location pdf $f(x-\theta)$. Show that the order statistics $T(X_1, ..., X_n) = (X_{(1)}, ..., X_{(n)})$ are a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ and no further reduction is possible.

Thus far I know and understand as a statement that when we don't have much information about the parameters of a distribution as in a non-parametric case, then the order statistics are the maximum reduction that we can achieve.  But how do I prove that the above statement holds true for $f(x-\theta)$.  Letting $Z_1, ..., Z_n$ be defined as $Z_i \equiv X_i - \theta$ for all $i=1,2,...,n$, is it enough to show that the pdf $f(x-\theta)$ becomes $f(z)$, which provides no information about $\theta$?

Comment: This appears to be a question from a course or textbook. Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: Yes. This is from the book Statistical Inference by Casella and Berger. I am reading the book on my own to learn the subject (and not posting my homework.) Thus far I know and understand as a statement that when we dont have much information about the parameters of a distribution as in a non-parammetric case, then the order statistics are the maximum reduction that we can achieve. But how do i prove that the above statement holds true for f(x-θ). @Silverfish

Comment: I suggest you edit that information into the question. Note that self-study questions get handled the same way regardless of whether it was homework for school or something you're teaching yourself (have a read of the wiki page I linked). You might also want to look at our [editing help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help) - you can do math typesetting here with Latex, e.g. writing `$x$` produces $x$.

Comment: Is it enough to show that considering the RV's Z1,..Zn such that Zi=Xi-θ (for all i=1,2,..n) the pdf f(x-θ) becomes f(z) which provides no information about θ?

Comment: Now that the OP has added the tag & stated what they understand thus far, I believe this meets our criteria. This Q should be considered on topic here, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is self-study -- Hint: Look at [Fisher's Factorization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher.E2.80.93Neyman_factorization_theorem) and show that the likelihood for $\theta$ is a function of the order statistics.

You'll also need to show that it is *minimal* sufficient (so that no "reduction" is possible) by showing that the likelihood ratio for two samples is free of $\theta$ iff they have the same order statistics.